# Selecting an active cell from a textbox value

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code:

```
Private Sub TextBox12_Change()
    Range("TextBox12.Value").Select
    TextBox3.Value = ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```

and `TextBox12` is currently being given the cell reference, I then need `TextBox3` to show the value of the active cell, any ideas?

Comment: `TextBox3.Value = Range(TextBox12.Value).Value`. And also read this: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Answer (score 0):

Remove " from code ...

```
On Error GoTo Fine
Range(TextBox12.Value).Select
TextBox3.Value = ActiveCell.Value
Fine:
```

Add on Error for Error in the Reference Value ...
You can use directly:

```
TextBox3.Value = Range(TextBox12.Value).Value
```

without selecting the cell.